# Custom Shipping module in user panel

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, sales, shipment

I have checked some tutorials to create custom shipping module in user panel where sellers can update carrier information and tracking  information. However, all are available for admin panel. I need to create in user panel. I know, how to create module for Magento. However, I am not able getting starting point where to start and which module I look through.

In Admin dashboard, admin can update the shipment information like which carrier is used for shipment and what is the tracking number. Is this module is using flat table in database?

Thanks :)

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you talking about the customer account dashboard? And who are these sellers, are the customers? please be more specific in what you want to do.

Comment: I am sorry. I will try to clear now, In Magento, one person can sell their products but I want multiples sellers.and they can sell their own products or items,   Customer can upload and modify his products from user account dashboard, and he can see his own producton user account dashboard. Customer can check the shipment info as we have functionality in admin dashboard. So I want that he can update the shipment for his products which products are in processing.

Comment: In that case, please check out Philwinkle's answer on a previous question an making Magento more 'etsy' style
http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5746/50 . Magento wasn't build for this kind of market place architecture and it will entail a lot more than just creating a custom shipping extension.

Comment: @SanderMangel... Thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 1):

The admin panel in Magento does not use the flat tables at all, as the flat tables are built on a per-store basis for the frontend store views.

Comment: Can I create shipping module on frontend  as I want to add shipping module on frontend end in user dashboard...